# How to add persona react-native sdk in android

Tags: react-native, sdk, certificate, digital, persona

I'm trying to implement digital verification in my app. I have done the iOS implementation now working on android In persona they have no documentation on the react-native page for android.
What I should do to move to native implementation or search for auto-linking?

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the Native implementation with the package and my App showing me the personal screens successfully.

here is Doc lin
https://docs.withpersona.com/docs/android-sdk-integration-guide

**Step 1:**

add this into app/build.gradle

```
maven { url 'https://sdk.withpersona.com/android/releases' }
```

**Step 2:**

add these line in app/src/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.withpersona.sdk:inquiry:1.1.1'
```